# EasyNote TE11HC touchpad not working

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 17.04, synaptics

I'm new to Linux, I installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my laptop and have no touchpad activity (tap, click, scroll), the external USB mouse works fine but would prefer the touchpad. My touchpad does not appear when I use xinput

**OS:** Ubuntu 17.04
**Laptop:** Packard Bell EasyNote TE11HC

---

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Holtek USB Gaming Mouse                   id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Holtek USB Gaming Mouse                   id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Holtek USB Gaming Mouse                   id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burned 16.04.3 LTS to a DVD and the touchpad is fully functional! Looks like 17.04 hasn't been given support for my device as of typing this.